# Primefaces upload javascript callback when selected files changed

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Is there a possiblity to have a callback in javascript or in the backing bean when the selected files in the primefaces upload has changed?
Background: after the user has chosen the files he can define some attributes for each file. So I want to upload the files only if the has defined these attributes and clicked the save button. If all is uploaded and then the attributes are defined, I have to place the files somewhere on the server I think.
The user must be able to select each file chosen for the upload to edit the attributes. There I need the chosen files after each changing.

I am using PF 5.2.6 and JSF 2.2.11.

Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

At least I solved it with this javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var fileUpload = PF('docUploadWidgetVar');
    var filesAr = fileUpload.files;

    Object.observe(filesAr, function(changes){
        console.log('upload files array has changed');
        filesAr.forEach(function(file) {
            console.log(file.name);
        });
    });
});
```

For this HTML 5 is needed as I know. I am using the advanced and multiple primefaces upload which is required for this anyway as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately this works until all files are removed with the upload cancel button.

Comment: Also Object.observe does not work with current versions of FF and IE.